# Images stretching over content column (like in Medium)

Tags: jquery, html, css

My blog just has a single content column (no sidebars). I want some images to stretch accross the full width of the screen (like it's possible with Medium -> https://medium.com/@rapsli/zum-himmelstor-und-wieder-zur%C3%BCck-635dd7012c5f). I know there is additional markup.

The markup I'm given is the following. Goal is to make the image stretch over the whole screen, while the text stays in the column.

```css
.row {
    max-width: 43.75rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.column, .columns {
    padding-left: .625rem;
    padding-right: .625rem;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.small-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
                
      <div class="">
          <article class="post column small-12">
            <section class="post--body">
                
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
        <p><img src="http://portugalresident.com/sites/default/files/field/image/gruta_benagil.jpg" alt="" class="full"></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
        <h3>A title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            </section>
          </article>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried to make the class "full" position: absolute and stretch it. This works, but obviously also covers the text that comes after the image.

Maybe there is some kind of jquery plugin that does the magic (adding additional markup as needed?). I'm kinda stuck here. Any help is welcome.

Update: It's the Zurb Grid System

Update: The content comes from a CMS. The width and height of the image is unknown resp. variable.

Comment: Why not use a CSS background image?

Comment: Can you post your css for row and column? Or is this bootstrap?

Comment: added additional CSS. I'm using Zurb.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution for now, relying on Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.full').each(function(){
    var height = $(this).height();
    if ($(this).parent().prop('tagName') == 'P') {
        $(this).parent().next().css('margin-top', height + 100 + 'px');    
    }

    else {
     $(this).next().css('margin-top', height + 100 + 'px');       
    }

})    
})
```

CSS that goes with it is pretty straight forward:

```
article img.full, article iframe.full {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```